# Javascript Control form fields posted to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

I have a Backone JS Model defined as below;

```
var Class = BaseModel.extend({
        idAttribute: "classId",
        urlRoot: "api/class",
        defaults: {
            "person": null,
            "classUrl": null,
            "classId": null
        }
}
```

Here person is itself actually an object/class which has 2 attributes; personName, personId

I have a UI form which has 2 fields;

> 1. Dropdown (called personName) : user can select from list of options
> 2. Textbox (called classUrl)

In my JS code, I am setting the JSON as below;

```
    var myJSON = {
        person : new Person(
            {
            "personId": $('#personName option:selected').data('personid'),
            "personName": this.$('#personName').val()
            }
        ),  
        classUrl: this.$('#classUrl').val()
}
```

Then I do;

```
this.model.save(myJSON, {
url:
success:
}
```

However the JSON which gets posted looks like;

```
{
person:,
classUrl:
personName:
}
```

I do not want the additional personName (corresponding to the dropdown) to be posted .

Just to add, I also have a changeAction called on change of any form field to do validation. But here I have;

```
changeAction: function (event) {
    var self = this;
    var target = event.target;
    var change = {};

    target.value = $.trim(target.value);
    change[target.name] = target.value;

    var tpmModel = this.model;
    tpmModel.set(change);

    var check = tpmModel.validateItem(target.id);
    if (check.isValid === false) {
    self.addValidationError(target.id, check.message);
    } else {
    self.removeValidationError(target.id);
    }
}
```

How do I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

When you need to specify the content that you want to post using backbone model, you need to use "data" inside the save method. It tells backbone to post something to server using the specified data inside the {}.
Like this.

```
  this.model.save(data: {"parameter1":"parameter1"
  ,"parameter2":"parameter2" })
```

Or

```
this.model.save(data: JSON.stringify(personObject))
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Of course you're right, my bad. I'll improve my answer. \0/